# Azure PowerShell Runbook - Error output details column empty

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have an Azure PowerShell 7.1 runbook in an automation account that is executing as expected. The only issue I have is that my Error Output within the running job screen is always missing the details column. This means I have to click on each record to see what is in it, which is very tedious.

**Note:** I am using the `Write-Error` command to generate these messages inside a `try/catch`

You can see what I mean in the following picture:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `graphical PowerShell` runbook type allows you to see the `details` column. After trying a workaround, I found a solution using a `graphical PowerShell runbook`.

I created a `graphical PowerShell runbook` and added my `PowerShell` onto the canvas. It was successfully executed and the following output with job details were displayed:

Aside from the runbook messages, you can also add `Input and Output`, as shown in the image below.

*I've just executed a sample* `write-error` *command*.

`Write-Error "Hi"`

`Automation Account -> Runbook (type:Graphical Powershell Runbook)`:

[image]

[image]

***Output:***

[image]